# choose what file input to initialize fine-uploader

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I've been looking for an already answered question and in the documentation but I didn't find anything.

I'd like to implement this library into a form to allow users to upload images and I have some questions about what and what not can this library do.

First, aside from the images file input, there are other hidden (`display: none;`) file inputs that the user triggers with a label and they have to stay that way (fine-upload shouldn't initialize those, as it's not neccesary).

I've already read that it supports submiting everything at the same time (this is important) but I'd also like to know if I can move the html template from the html's `<head>` tag to another file (i.e. a scripts.js file).

Answer (score 0):

> if I can move the html template from the html's `<head>` tag to another file

Makes no difference where the Fine Uploader template lives, as long as it is available in the DOM by the time a Fine Uploader instance is constructed.

Comment: You mean I can place it wherever I like but I have to include it inside the html by the time the server sends all the content to the client? I meant if Fine uploader instance can read it from a scripts.js file. What about the hidden file inputs? If they are initialize will it affect anything? Like the name attribute or showing the UI alongside the label?